# jQuery append minimize

Tags: jquery, append

is there a trick to save time and readability for .append ?

Exemple:

```
$('body').append("<div class='overlay'></div>"); // Ordinary
$('body').append("div.overlay"); // Maybe ?
```

Thanks.

Comment: Check the quotes. Use only `$('body').append("<div class='overlay'></div>")`. Remove the second statement

Comment: Thank you , but it does not answer my question, I wonder if there is a way to do otherwise.

Comment: Save time *how*? Runtime? Typing time? What does "save readability" mean? What is it about "ordinary" you have a problem with?

Comment: A way to make cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that particular example, you can do it like this:

```
$('body').append($("<div>").addClass("overlay"));
```

or

```
$("<div>").addClass("overlay").appendTo('body');
```

I don't know that those "saves time and readability," but they're the only reasonable alternatives I can come up with.

Comment: You mean `$('<div />')` in the first example

Comment: @Tushar: No, I don't. jQuery doesn't require XHTML, and `<div />` is **only** valid in XHTML (not HTML). In theory, I should be writing `$("<div></div>")`, but jQuery has always supported just giving a start tag for non-void elements if you're *just* giving the tag name.